# android- ' Cannot resolve method getSystemService'- when registering alarm on system reboot

Tags: java, android

I am registering the alarm when system reboot since alarm will be killed after the system rebooted, but I get the error of 'Cannot resolve method getSystemService()', is it syntax error...

can Context be used in this case since this function should be called when the phone has been rebooted...

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



public class RebootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyBroadcast ";

    public  RebootBroadcast () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action) {
                case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:



                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,intent,0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService();
                    AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService();

                    long timeAtButtonClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long tenSecondsInMillis = 1000 * 10;
                    long nextInMillis = 1000 * 20;


                    String myDate = "2020/05/09 18:00:00";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date = null;
                    try {
                        date = sdf.parse(myDate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    long millis = date.getTime();

                    //long diff = millis - timeAtButtonClick;


                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   millis, pendingIntent);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to

```
(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService()
```

```
(AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getSystemService` on a Context, hence, why it doesn't work in your `ALARM_SERVICE`. You can store the context you already pass in as a field and call getSystemService on that.